# How to add white space in regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `{{my name}}` and i want to add white space in regular expression

```
var str = "{{my name}}";

var patt1 = /\{{\w{1,}\}}/gi; 

var result = str.match(patt1);

console.log(result);
```

But result in not match.

Any solution for this.

Comment: Where do you want to add the white space?

Comment: using your  pattern.. /{{\w{1,}\ \w{1,}}}/gi

Comment: \s - will match exact one space

Comment: Hey there, following up on this, did one of the answers solve it for you, or is the question still there?

Answer (score 2):

Give the word character`\w` and the space character`\s` inside character class`[]`,

```
> var patt1 = /\{\{[\w\s]+\}\}/gi; 
undefined
> var result = str.match(patt1);
undefined
> console.log(result);
[ '{{my name}}' ]
```

The above regex is as same as `/\{\{[\w\s]{1,}\}\}/gi`

**Explanation:**

- `\{` - Matches a literal `{` symbol.
- `\{` - Matches a literal `{` symbol.
- `[\w\s]+` - word character and space character are given inside Character class. It matches one or more word or space character.
- `\}` - Matches a literal `}` symbol.
- `\}` - Matches a literal `}` symbol.

Comment: i also want string that contains a sequence of at least 1

Comment: `[\w\s]+` matches word character or space character one or more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on

```
^\{\{[a-z]*\s[a-z]*\}\}$
```

Explanation:

- \{ - Matches a literal { symbol.
- \{ - Matches a literal { symbol.
- [a-z]* - will match zero or more characters
- \s - will match exact one space
- \} - Matches a literal } symbol.
- \} - Matches a literal } symbol.

If you want compulsory character then use + instead of *.

Answer (score 0):

To match this pattern, use this simple regex:

```
{{[^}]+}}
```

The [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rR9lJ8) shows you what the pattern matches and doesn't match.

In JS:

```
match = subject.match(/{{[^}]+}}/);
```

To do a replacement around the pattern, use this:

```
result = subject.replace(/{{[^}]+}}/g, "Something$0Something_else");
```

**Explanation**

- `{{` matches your two opening braces
- `[^}]+` matches one or more chars that are not a closing brace
- `}}` matches your two closing braces

Comment: FYI added demo of what the pattern matches and doesn't match. :)